# Dynamically Created Textboxes Not Bound To Model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My viewmodel contains a list of strings:

```
public class SupplierViewModel
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public List<string> Numbers;
}
```

The user can add any number of strings in the view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Numbers)
    </div>

    <div id="allNumbers">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Numbers.Count; i++)
        {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Numbers[i])
        </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div id="newNumber" style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" name="Numbers[#]" style="display:block;" />
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="addNumber" >Add</button>
```

This is done on the client side with jquery:

```
var container = $('#allNumbers');
$('#addNumber').click(function () {
    var index = container.children().length;
    var clone = $('#newNumber').clone();
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
    container.append(clone.html());
});
```

My problem is that none of the dynamically added strings are sent back to the controller even tough they are all named "Numbers[i]".
What am I missing here?

Comment: That looks familiar code :). Its not binding on post back because `Numbers` is a field, not a property. Change it to `public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes I remember you! :D Thanks for helping me again that was it. I'll work on the client sided removing of items now so there's a good chance you'll see this code again. If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numbers` is a field and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the value of a field. You need to make it a property by adding getters/setters

```
public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }
```